# jQuery save location on page based on element IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a page that has a long list of items that is loaded through ajax. There is a button that when clicked will expand details under these items (through ajax). This works great however if the user has scrolled down the page a little bit, then clicks the button, they lose the spot they're on (since the button is loading much more data than was there originally).

I think the best way to fix this is to remember where they were at on the page based on a div  element ID as they are scrolling. So as you're scrolling, each line item has an ID that jQuery is reading and saving the one they're currently at. Then after they click the button I can manually scroll them to that same ID.

Can this be done or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: what do you mean "they lose the spot they're on"? are you stopping the default action clicking action?

Comment: When you load in new content, insert it all at once and correct the scroll position at the same time.

Comment: Basically there is a list of information. They might scroll down the page, click a button which loads the same list with more information. The page itself stays in the same spot but there is more information which pushes what they were reading further down. That is what I mean that they lose the spot they're on.